# How do you make the debugger refresh variables automatically on entry

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

As the title says, How to make real-time refresh, I am working on a feature, but it does not do real-time update, but this is exactly the feature I need.

I want to implement variable auto-refresh

Comment: there's no much more to say than "implement the DAP"... especially not without the context of a [mre] of what you have so far